# Normal and regular space

Tags: general-topology

**Prove or disprove**: *Every normal space is a regular space.*

> Disprove by the following example

$X=\{a,b,c\}$ and $\tau=\{∅,X,\{a\} \}$

*The problem is how to show this* *example is a normal space ?*

**Definition of Normal space**: a space $X$ is called normal space iff for every pair $L$ , $M$ of disjoint closed sets in $X$ there exists open sets $G$ and $H$ s.t $L⊂G$ and $M⊂H$ and $G ∩ H = ∅$

Comment: You should begin by writing down the definition of a normal space.

Comment: @StefanMesken thank u i forgot

Comment: So... what are the pairs of closed disjoint sets in $X$?

Comment: @StefanMesken just phi and $X$

Comment: No. Try again...

Comment: @StefanMesken if we take tau complement then the set {b,c} is also a closed set but the set {a} is not closed

Comment: So $\{b,c\}$ is closed and $\emptyset$ is closed... Don't you think they are disjoint?

Comment: @StefanMesken they are disjoint, but to be honest i thought that we must choose the closed sets from tau not tau complement

Comment: @StefanMesken so the open sets are $X$ and phi

Comment: A set $C$ is closed (relative to the topology $\tau$) if and only if $X \setminus C \in \tau$.

Comment: $\{a\}$ is open as well.

Comment: @StefanMesken so for the set {a} we could say that phi is a subset of the set {a}

Comment: That's true but I don't see how it's relevant to your question. There are two pairs of disjoint closed sets, namely $\emptyset, X$ and $\emptyset, \{b,c\}$. Your job is it to find, for each of these pairs, a corresponding pair of open sets that satisfies the requirements. For the pair $\emptyset, X$ we can take $\emptyset, X$, since they are open as well and satisfy the requirements. How about $\emptyset, \{b,c\}$?

Comment: @StefanMesken yes it was just a que. And thank u sir

Comment: Well, what about $\emptyset, \{b,c \}$ then? What's the corresponding pair of disjoint open sets?

Comment: @StefanMesken the open sets will be $\emptyset$ since its subset of itself and the other open set is the space $X$ which the set $\{b,c \}$ is a subset of and at the end we intersect the both open sets which give us emptyset

Comment: Correct. You have thus verified the normality of the space $(X, \tau)$.

Comment: @StefanMesken thnx sir

Comment: The usual definition of normal space includes the condition that it is a $T_1$ space. With this def'n it is obvious that normal implies regular. With the def'n in the Q, you have an example of a normal space that is not regular because the point $a$ is not in the closed set $\{b,c\}$ but the sets $\{a\}, \{b,c\}$ cannot be completely separated by open sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closed sets of $X$ are the complements of the open sets, hence 
we have three of them: $\emptyset, X, \{b,c\}$. The only pairs of disjoint closed subsets occur when we have one of them be $\emptyset$ (as the other $2$ intersect), and in that case we can choose $\emptyset$ as its open neighbourhood, and $X$ for the other one (and these are disjoint open neighbourhoods).
This shows that $(X,\tau)$ is normal.

On the other hand, $a \notin \{b,c\}$ and the latter set is closed as we saw.
The only open neighbourhood of $\{b,c\}$ is $X$ and this intersects any neighbourhood of $a$ (in at least $a$ itself). So we cannot separate the point $a$ and the closed set $\{b,c\}$ by disjoint open neighbourhoods.
This shows that $(X,\tau)$ is not regular.

Comment: Thanks sir, u cleared it very well...

Comment: @user517932 glad it helped you.